# can anyone help me with mysql connection (Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just registered new domain to upload my site for hosting. But i have a problem with connection to database, i cannot connect to database. When i try to connect to database, it said:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet',
system error: 110
```

Some people said that i have to create TCP port (3306) in firewall. I have tried with this way, but i cannot create that port. I got stuck with this a few days ago :( can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank in advance!

Comment: first stop firewall and check whether it's working. If so, post the problem in http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of your services, Make sure MySQL is running, if so, Do restart your MySQL. sometimes I got this error. What I did is check the services and restarted the MySQL and it was solved.

Comment: i already tried this way, but that problem is still come out.